# How to set if condition for formulas in excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement

How can I make an if statement in excel that will returns 999 if the A3 cell has this information (Your order qualifies for FREE Shipping Choose this option at checkout. See detail) otherwise print the number(for example for this information "This seller has only 3 of these available. To see if more are available from another seller, go to the product detail page" I would like to print 3). I attached what I've done by now. I will appreciate any help.

```
=IF(A2="Your order qualifies for FREE Shipping Choose this option at checkout. See detail",999,TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)*1,"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show a table example with desired output?

Comment: Yes. I will show now.

Comment: Cell A2: This seller has only 3 of these available. To see if more are available from another seller, go to the product detail page.Cell: A3:Your order qualifies for FREE Shipping Choose this option at checkout. See detail. For cell A2 I would like to output 3 in the cell B2. For cell A3 i would like to output 999 in the cell B3. So I would like to output 999 for this information "Your order qualifies for FREE Shipping Choose this option at checkout. See detail" otherwise to print the number.

Comment: @Andrei Ghervan: please edit your question instead of adding information in commments

Comment: I edited now the question.